# Revit, how to get position, length and height in a selected wall

Tags: c#, parameters, get, project, revit

I have this code and I don't know how I can display the position, the height, and the length of my selected wall:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection;
using Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
namespace PickSelectionFiltered
{
    [TransactionAttribute(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    [RegenerationAttribute(RegenerationOption.Manual)] 

    public class Class1: IExternalCommand
    {
        public class MySelectionFilter : ISelectionFilter
        {
            Document m_doc = null;

            public bool AllowElement(Element element)
            {
                return element is Wall;
            }
            public bool AllowReference(Reference refer, XYZ point)
            {
                GeometryObject geoObject = 
                m_doc.GetElement(refer)
                     .GetGeometryObjectFromReference(refer);
                return geoObject != null && geoObject is Face;
            }
        }


        public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, 
          ref string message, ElementSet elements)
        {
            //Get application and document objects
            UIDocument uidoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument;

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Reference selRef = 
                      uidoc.Selection.PickObject(ObjectType.Element, 
                        new MySelectionFilter(), "select a room");
                    /*
                     * Add the code to get position, lenght and height
                     * */
                }

            } catch (Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.OperationCanceledException) { }

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The position of the wall is based on it's driving curve, obtained from the wall as a LocationCurve:

```
Wall wall = document.GetReference(setRef) as Wall;
if (wall != null)
{
    LocationCurve locationCurve = wall.Location as LocationCurve;
    XYZ endPoint0 = locationCurve.Curve.get_EndPoint[0];
    XYZ endPoint1 = locationCurve.Curve.get_EndPoint[1];
}
```

The length of the wall is obtained from the wall's parameter:

```
BuiltInParameter.CURVE_ELEM_LENGTH
```

The width of the wall is obtained from the wall type's parameter:

```
BuiltInParameter.WALL_ATTR_WIDTH_PARAM
```

This is for a standard wall, and would not be applicable to special wall types like curtain walls and stacked walls.

Comment: Be cautious of the location curve.  It actually only provides the wall centreline and therefore the endpoints usually end up in the middle of a corner joint, not necessarily the endpoints of a wall.

Answer (score 0):

Open the saved file in Revit and follow the instructions below to answer the question.

Add a new 'Level 3, height 6650mm

⚫ Change the Top constraint' of the external walls to the new 'Level 3'

What is the new area of the north-facing wall?

A. 180.012 Sq. m

B. 184,097 Sq. m

о

C. 170.034 Sq. m

O

D. 160.067 Sq. m

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!